# I'm doing both operation updating the item and sorting in list in Default Dispatcher java.util.ConcurrentModificationException error is coming

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, threadpool, coroutine

While i'm using Default Dispatcher for updating the items in list and then sort the list i some time face
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException error. Question is do i have to make two difference
Default Dispatcher code block one for updating items in list and other for sorting items in list.

code:-

```
 withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                for (item in listOfLocation) {
                    val distanceInMeter = ClsGlobel.calculateDistance(
                        item.lat, item.lon, it.latitude, it.longitude
                    ) * 1000
                    listOfLocation[listOfLocation.indexOf(item)] =
                        SavedLocation(item.id, item.lat, item.lon, distanceInMeter, item.areaName)
                }

                listOfLocation.sortBy { it.distance }
                Log.e(
                    "tag", " Default: "
                            + Thread.currentThread().name
                )
            }
```

Comment: i think Dispatchers.Default uses Thread Pool so some time it happened that one thread update the item from list while other thread is doing sorting in list so at that time this error may occur.

Comment: Yes, the `Default` dispatcher uses a thread pool (in both Kotlin/JVM and Kotlin/Native), with a minimum of 2 threads. See https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-default.html

Comment: @Tenfour04 i have not call it multiple time

Comment: Oops, I didn’t look closely at your code. You’re doing the concurrent modification right there in your loop! See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with coroutines or threads. You are modifying your list while iterating it with its iterator (“concurrent modification”), which is not permitted. You cannot mutate a List while iterating it in a for loop that uses its Iterator.

So, change it to not use the List’s Iterator. Change this:

```
for (item in listOfLocation) {
    val distanceInMeter = ClsGlobel.calculateDistance(
            item.lat, item.lon, it.latitude, it.longitude
        ) * 1000
    listOfLocation[listOfLocation.indexOf(item)] =
        SavedLocation(item.id, item.lat, item.lon, distanceInMeter, item.areaName)
}
```

to

```
for (i in listOfLocation.indices) {
    val item = listOfLocation[i]
    val distanceInMeter = ClsGlobel.calculateDistance(
            item.lat, item.lon, it.latitude, it.longitude
        ) * 1000
    listOfLocation[i] =
        SavedLocation(item.id, item.lat, item.lon, distanceInMeter, item.areaName)
}
```

This also changes your code complexity from O(n^2) to O(n).

Comment: thanks for the solution this runs faster i have measure time of execution thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> The java.util.concurrentmodificationexception is an error in Java. The
> error occurs when the iterator is traversing a list, and a command is
> used to change an element’s value during that traversal

seems your listOfLocation is too large. and you are sorting it while it's still in progress
try something like this. [asSequence](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-sequence.html)

```
   listOfLocation
    .asSequence
    .map{
        //calculate distanceInMeter etc
    }
    .sortBy { it.distance }
```

and why do you use Default dispatcher? use IO

Comment: i m using Default dispatcher because the list is in memory so there is no IO operation so im using Default dispatcher for CPU-intensive operations such as filtering,Updating,sorting or any other calculation.

Comment: I think solution will work i will try this. Thank for solution.

Comment: This cannot possibly be the issue. Code is run orderly. The runtime doesn’t randomly decide to start doing things in parallel because it’s taking a while and risking crashes without you programming it to.